# Transform 3D to PointCloud

Tags: matlab, 3d, shapes, matlab-cvst, point-clouds

I'm working with Persistent Homology and I need cloud points of common 3D shapes to be able to test my methods.

The problem is that I'm a Java programmer and Java doesn't offer such tools, but I'm pretty sure Matlab does... I tried reading about this here:

```
http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/pcfitsphere.html
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sphere.html
http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/pcshow.html#inputarg_ptCloud
```

Those links provide information on Spheres and PointClouds, but I've never programmed on matlab so I can't even propose code.

Is there a way to take a 3d shape, get it's point cloud and print the point cloud on the console?
Like:

x0, y0, z0

x1, y1, z1

x2, y2, z2

...
What I was doing was creating a Java class that printed random points based on a function, so for example I'd give my program the function of a sphere... But it gets super complicated when I'm trying to create functions of pyramids or three-torus.

Comment: I think the same approach you attempted in Java would be the way to go in Matlab.

Comment: it sounds like you're asking for equations that describe certain 3d shapes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a MATLAB example of [points inside a sphere](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/numbers-placed-randomly-within-volume-of-sphere.html):

```
% random points in spherical coordinates
N = 1000;
theta = 2*pi*rand(N,1);
phi = asin(2*rand(N,1)-1);
radii = 3*(rand(N,1).^(1/3));

% convert to cartesian
[x,y,z] = sph2cart(theta, phi, radii);

% plot
scatter3(x, y, z, 10, 'filled')
axis vis3d equal, grid on, box on
xlabel X, ylabel Y, zlabel Z
```

[image: sphere-cloud]

See [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html) for reference.

---

## EDIT

Here is another example for generating points inside a pyramid.

This time I'm taking a brute-force approach by simply generating lots of random 3d points in the [0,1] cube, and then filtering them by [testing which points are inside the pyramid convex polyhedron](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101396-is-there-a-function-in-matlab-for-detecting-points-inside-a-polyhedron) (using Delaunay triangulation).

```
% random points
N = 3000;
XYZ = rand(N,3);

% unit pyramid in [0,1]
V = [0   0   0 ;
     1   0   0 ;
     1   1   0 ;
     0   1   0 ;
     0.5 0.5 0 ;
     0.5 0.5 sqrt(2)/2];

% delaunay triangulation
DT = delaunayn(V);

% determine points within
in = ~isnan(tsearchn(V, DT, XYZ));

% plot
scatter3(XYZ(in,1), XYZ(in,2), XYZ(in,3), 8, 'filled')
view(3), axis vis3d equal, grid on, box on
axis([0 1 0 1 0 1])
xlabel X, ylabel Y, zlabel Z

% overlay pyramid
hold on
h = tetramesh(DT, V);
set(h, 'FaceAlpha',0.1, 'EdgeColor','m', 'FaceColor','m')
hold off
```

[image: pyramid-cloud]

Comment: WOW! Amazing. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, you already did a lot, but I'd like to know if there is a way to print those coordinates like:
x0, y0, z0;
x1, y1, z1;
...

Comment: sure that's the easy part :) You can use functions like [`CSVWRITE`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvwrite.html) or [`DLMWRITE`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html) or just plain old `FPRINTF`. For the first example: `csvwrite('sphere.csv', [x y z])`, and for the second example, say: `dlmwrite('pyramid.csv', XYZ(in,:), 'precision','%.9f')`

Comment: Nice! One last thing, I just realized the points are also inside the the shapes. I also need to plot the points only on the surface. Is this possible?

Comment: oh that's actually a bit different.. For the sphere case, you can easily modify the code by setting a fixed radius, so change it to `radii = 3` (this is explained in the link provided: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/numbers-placed-randomly-within-volume-of-sphere.html). For the other case, delaunay triangulation is not gonna wok, sorry!

Comment: this is not an easy problem.. Browsing mathematica.SE, you can find some interesting solutions over there: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77131/966, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13038/966, and many more.. You might also get pointers if you properly ask this over at [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Yes I've been searching the web for this a week go with no success. I thought that probably Matlab had a way to generalize this problem to any given 3d shape. I'll ask, thanks.

Comment: I guess I'm relying too much on external knowledge. I'll have to study spherical and polar coordinates in order to find a generalization for a set of shapes. This will take some time haha. Anyway, thanks for your time and dedication. :)